# Retrieving a php virtual document name

Tags: php

I would like to retrieve a snippet of i.e.: `www.something.com/something2/something3/page1.php?var1=1&var2=2`

Precisely how to get `'page1.php'` from the above by `$_SERVER`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have done so far except posting here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$path = parse_url('www.something.com/.../page1.php?var1=1&var2=2', PHP_URL_PATH);
echo basename($path);
```

http://php.net/parse_url
http://php.net/basename